# What is speed of using keysSortedByValueUsingComparator method on a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary that I want to print out as key: value in sorted order (where the keys are such that key with lower value is printed first).

To do this, I am using the keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: method of NSDictionary like below.

Does anyone know if the underlying implementation uses a quick sort like approach and achieves O(N*logN) or is it comparing every object with every other object leading to O(N^2) complexity?

Example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *hashTable = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
....
code that adds a bunch of Objects to the hashtable dictionary with key = NSString and value = NSNumber object
....
NSArray * sortedKeys = [hashTable keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
           if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue])
           {
               return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
           }

           if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue])
           {
               return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
           }

           return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
       }];

for (NSString *nextKey in sortedKeys)
{
   NSLog(@"%@: %@",nextKey,hashTable[nextKey]);
}
```

Comment: The only relevant question is: is it fast enough for my app?  I think it's safe to assume that Apple programmers are not complete idiots, and don't use a bubble sort for this method.

Comment: @Yvette, exactly why I voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to use a merge sort - which of course is O(*n* log *n*). Other sorting methods are known to use quicksort.

How to guess: Place a breakpoint inside your comparator block and read the stack trace when it gets hit. In your code you'll see the comparator is being called by `CFSimpleMergeSort`. It's a good guess that is a merge sort unless Apple programmers have an interesting naming scheme!

Maybe how to find out for sure: The main `NS` collections are toll-free bridged to their `CF` counterparts, and `CF` source is available from Apple's open source site. Search for `CFArray.c`, `CFDictionary.c` etc. and you'll find the source. This will not include all the `NS` methods, hence the "maybe find out", but it shows how these types work.

HTH

Comment: On a previous WWDC Apple explained they are using various strategies to sort arrays. I wouldn't draw conclusions from _one_ example.

Comment: @gnasher729 - That is true. A few different data set sizes (10, 1000, 1000000) were used to see if the algorithm was changed and it appeared not to be – that is *not* definitive in anyway of course, but it is a reasonable guess they are sticking with merge sort here. Looking at Apple's open source, for those types it is available, will be definitive.